# Download failing for some specific URLs in Android app

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-download-manager

Here is some kotlin code I have that is used to implement a download feature in an Android app (using DownloadManager):
(It is not the whole code, but the relevant part for my question)

```
    var brdCstRcvr = object: BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
            val id = p1?.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1)

            if (id == downloadID) {
                val mgr = applicationContext.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
                val uri:Uri? = mgr.getUriForDownloadedFile(downloadID)

                if (uri == null) {
                    println("We have a problem with this URL: ${urlStr.text.toString()}")
                    return
                }

                val inputStream: InputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri!!)!!
                .... more useful code not relevant to the question .....
            }
        }
        .........
    }
```

Though it is mostly working I have a problem with one case. This is the shape of the URL causing trouble:

http://192.168.77.123/FOLDER/Sample.mp3

When running the app I get this message:

```
We have a problem with this URL: http://192.168.77.123/FOLDER/Sample.mp3
```

(showing that uri is null)

The other URLs I have used with no issue are all of type https://example.site.net/Sample.mp3

The URL with problems is http (instead of https) and it is on my local network.
But I am not sure this is the cause of the issue.

Any idea on how to catch the cause of this would be helpful.

Comment: `When running the app I get this message:

We have a problem with this URL` That is again your own message. Better: tell that mgr.getUriForDownloadedFile() returns null. I made such a remark twice before to you.

Comment: `code not relevant to the question .....` As you have a problem with your code it looks better to me to post complete code. Then we can see if all is relevant and well done.

Comment: `http (instead of https) and it is on my local network. But I am not sure this is the cause of the issue.` Added usesCleartextTraffic to application tag in manifest file?

Comment: Thanks for the usesCleartextTraffic tip, it worked. I added it to the manifest file. It seems like the default is true anyway. But still seeing the result, it means it needs to be there.